# Convert a string to a dictionary in Python?

Tags: python, json, twitter

I am pulling data from twitter, which is in the structure of a python dictionary, but the data is held in a string variable.

How can I convert this string variable to a dictionary in Python?

Thanks for the help!

EDIT: [Here](https://docs.google.com/document/pub?id=1SkDTIV95_KPBnOxmoWx4n5uhvSBSayJ_RjXzpgY0sEc) is an example of the data.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You are probably looking for the [json](http://docs.python.org/library/json.html#module-json) module.

For example,

```
In [165]: json.loads('{"a": 0, "c": 0, "b": 0}')
Out[165]: {u'a': 0, u'b': 0, u'c': 0}
```

Comment: Thank you! Do you have any idea why it would give me: ValueError: Unterminated string starting at: line 1 column 1403 (char 1403)? This happens on multiple tweets - I just don't know what exactly causes it.

Comment: @Andrew: Post the text starting from 1402.

Comment: Could you please explain to me how to do that easily?

Comment: @Andrew: It looks like there are unescaped quotation marks which are messing up json. Can you show us the code you are using to download this string?

Comment: Thank you so much for your help, but I've figured out the problem. I just have to use regex to look for oddly placed quotes and then replace them with spaces.

Comment: @Andrew: I'm glad you found a solution!

Answer (score 3):

As unutbu says, you should use the json module.
Using your example data, I can do this:

```
import json
import codecs
tweet = codecs.open('example.txt', encoding='utf8').read()
data = json.loads(tweet)
print keys(data)
```

With this result:

```
[u'favorited', u'in_reply_to_user_id', u'retweeted_status', u'contributors', u'truncated', u'entities', u'text', u'created_at', u'retweeted', u'in_reply_to_status_id', u'coordinates', u'id', u'source', u'in_reply_to_status_id_str', u'in_reply_to_screen_name', u'id_str', u'place', u'retweet_count', u'geo', u'in_reply_to_user_id_str', u'user']
```

No error messages.  Perhaps you could include some example data for the error case along with the relevant code?